# Improving the time complexity in priority queue in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity, priority-queue

In the code below, I am getting time out for larger vector length, though it is working for smaller length vector.

```
     long priceCalculate(vector < int > a, long k) {
        long price = 0;
        priority_queue<int>pq(a.begin(),a.end());
        while(--k>=0){
            int x = pq.top();
            price = price + x;
            pq.pop();
            pq.push(x-1);
        }
        return price;
    }
```

I have an array of numbers. I have to add the maximum number to price and then decrement that number by 1. Again find the maximum number and so on. I have to repeat this process for k times.
Is there any better data structure than priority queue which has less time complexity?

Below is the code using vector sort:

```
    struct mclass {
        public: bool operator()(int x, int y) {
            return (x > y);
        }
    }
    compare;
    long priceCalculate(vector < int > a, long k) {

        long price = 0;
        sort(a.begin(), a.end(), compare);
        while (--k >= 0) {
            if (a[0] > 0) {

                price = price + a[0];
                a[0] = a[0] - 1;

                sort(a.begin(), a.end(), compare);
            }
        }
        return price;
    }
```

But this is also giving timeout on large input length.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is doing. You have this heap of elements, you take out the top, add it to `price`, decrement it and reinsert it into the queue and repeat this for`k-1` times.  Do you have an idea about how big `k` is in the average case, with respect to `a`? If `k` is about as big as `a` you can just sort the vector and avoid using the priority queue (since popping n elements takes O(n log n) time anyway).

Comment: Edited the question with the code logic.

Comment: Why not use a vector, sort so the max is the first element.  Then you can keep decrementing that until it is less the the next element. then you move on to the next element and decrement it.  Then you go back to the first element. rinse and repeat.  This is a lot less the O(K*N*logN) comparisons.

Comment: `getting time out` - where ?

Comment: You don't need to reinsert the decremented number back into the queue. Here's a sketch of the algorithm. Pop the top number. Keep decrementing and adding it until it becomes equal to the new top (until then, it's clearly still the largest). Pop another element. Keep decrementing and adding it *twice* until it becomes equal to the new top (this simulates two elements taking turns becoming the largest). Pop yet third element, keep decrementing and adding it *thrice*. And so on.

Comment: Further improvement can be achieved by observing that "keep decrementing and adding" part is equivalent to calculating a sum of arithmetic progression, which can be expressed in closed form.

Comment: If you want the best time complexity, go Brodal queues. If you want _optimization_, go Codereview.

Answer (score 0):

For the vector solution you should be able to gain performance by avoiding `sort` inside the loop.

After

```
a[0] = a[0] - 1;
```

you can do something like the (pseudo) code below instead of calling `sort`:

```
tmp = 0;
for j = 1 to end-1
{
    if a[0] < a[j] 
        ++tmp
    else
        break
 }
 swap a[0], a[tmp]
```

to place the decremented value correctly in the sorted vector, i.e. since the vector is sorted from start, you'll only need to find the first element which is less or equal to the decremented value and swap the element just before with [0]. This should be faster than `sort` that has to go through the whole vector.

**Examples of algorithm**

```
// Vector after decremt
9, 10, 9, 5, 3, 2
    ^
    tmp = 1

// Vector after swap
10, 9, 9, 5, 3, 2
```

---

```
// Vector after decremt
9, 10, 10, 5, 3, 2
       ^
       tmp = 2

// Vector after swap
10, 10, 9, 5, 3, 2
```

**Performance**

I compared my approach with the vector example from OP:

```
k = 1000
vector.size = 10000000
vector filled with random numbers in range 0..9999
compiled with g++ -O3

My approach:
    real 0.83
    user 0.78
    sys 0.05

OPs vector approach
    real 119.42
    user 119.42
    sys 0.04
```

Answer (score 0):

The sorting code has two performance problems:

1. You are resorting the `vector<>` in every iteration. Even if your sorting algorithm is insertion sort (which would be best in this case), it still needs to touch every position in the vector before it can declare the `vector<>` sorted.
2. To make matters worse, you are sorting the values you want to work with to the front of the vector, requiring the subsequent `sort()` call to shift almost all elements.

Consequently, you can achieve huge speedups by

1. Reversing the sort order, so that you are only interacting with the end of the `vector<>`.
2. Sort only once, then update the `vector<>` by scanning to the right position *from the end*, and inserting the new value there.

You can also take a closer look at what your algorithm is doing: It only ever operates on the tail of the `vector<>` which has constant value, removing entries from it, and reinserting them, decremented by one, in front of it. I think you should be able to significantly simplify your algorithm with that knowledge, leading to even more significant speedups. In the end, you can remove that tail from the `vector<>` entirely: It's completely described by its length and its value, and all its elements can be manipulated in a single operation. Your algorithm should take no time at all once you are through optimizing it...